# How to search for a specific keyword in html page source code with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm aiming to find out how can I search for a specific keyword in the html page source code and return value as True/False. Depending if the keyword has been found or not.

Specific keyword I'm looking for is 'cdn.secomapp.com'

For now my code looks like this:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_1 = "https://cheapchicsdesigns.com"
keyword ='cdn.secomapp.com'
page = request.urlopen(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.find_all("head", string=keyword)
```

but when I run this it then returns an empty list:

```
[]
```

Could someone help with this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only purpose is to see whether the keyword is present or not, then you don't need to construct a BeautifulSoup object.

```
from urllib import request

url_1 = "https://cheapchicsdesigns.com"
keyword ='cdn.secomapp.com'
page = request.urlopen(url_1)

print(keyword in page.read())
```

But I would recommend you to use `requests` as it's more easy

```
import requests

url_1 = "https://cheapchicsdesigns.com"
keyword ='cdn.secomapp.com'

res = requests.get(url_1)

print(keyword in res.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_1 = "https://cheapchicsdesigns.com"
keyword ='cdn.secomapp.com'
page = request.urlopen(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(keyword in soup.text)
```

prints:

```
True
```

---

Or:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_1 = "https://cheapchicsdesigns.com"
keyword ='cdn.secomapp.com'
page = requests.get(url_1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(keyword in soup.text)
```

prints:

```
True
```

Comment: It returned 'False' for some reason. I used exactly same code as you provided above. Checked with different keywords and it still returns 'False'. Would you know what can cause this? thx

Comment: What python version do you run? @Baobab1988